# Add Custom Maps(Saved Maps) to Google Maps SDK in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, google-maps

I was wondering if there's any way, to add one of your already saved maps in Google Maps to the Google Maps SDK, so I can make a viewcontroller which shows a saved map over google maps.

Comment: Have you tried yet?

Comment: I have no idea what to begin with, and I cant seem to find any documentation about it either.

Comment: What kind of saved maps ?

Comment: The ones you can create on the web interface of Google Maps, under Your Places-> Maps